# Does shear stress depend on coordinates and can be transformed from tangential pressure by coordinate transformation？

Tags: fluid-dynamics, stress-energy-momentum-tensor

In spherical coordinate (t, r, θ, φ), the energy-momentum tensor of a no shear stress fluid is diagonal. When converting to Cartesian coordinate, energy-momentum tensor has nonzero off-diagonal elements and shear stresses present. Does this mean shear stress depend on coordinates? Is tangential pressure related to shear stress?

Once the shear stress depend on coordinates, a problem has arisen. Considering interior Schwarzschild metric in [this website](https://handwiki.org/wiki/Physics:Interior_Schwarzschild_metric), the source of solution is a non-rotating spherical body which consists of an incompressible fluid and the solution is static. When converting to Cartesian coordinate, the shear stress presents, which means that the fluid is not static. Why does this contradictory conclusion arise?